# Is there a problem with a two-sided posterior p-value?

Tags: bayesian, p-value

I'm reading Koop's Bayesian Econometrics, and in page 103, where he presents an algorithm to calculate the p-value, it seems that isn't exactly sure which tail to consider...

> Step 7: Calculate the proportion of the S draws for which the
> statistics using the replicated data are smaller than the statistics
> using the original data. If this number is less than 0.5, then you
> this is the p-value, otherwise do 1 minus this number.
> [It's a summary of the paragraph]

It seems that he is unsure whether to consider $q=P(T(y_{\text{rep}}) \geq T(y) \mid y)$ or $1-q$. Why is that? Shouldn't this have been decided up front, when he chose $T(\cdot)$, and what property $T$ is supposed to represent?

Also, would there be any problem in considering a two-sided p-value, i.e. in the sense of $p=2\min(q,1-q)$, or $P(|T(y_{\text{rep}})| \geq |T(y)| \mid y)$?